Fill the inner face
I'm a beginner in Blender, and currently, I want to fill the inner wall of a ear canal model while keeping the shape of the inner wall consistent with the outer wall.
you can get my file from 
My expectation is to fill the inner wall of the example to make it approximate the target (where the example is derived by removing the inner wall from the target).


Use a tool like Quad Remesh or a app like Instant Meshes to retopologize your object with more quads:

Select the vertices on the edges, you can for example use ShiftG > Amount of Adjacent Faces to select similar vertices which will select a lot of them:

Extend the selection with Ctrl+

Remove the selection, clean up the single vertices until you have a nice edge:

Select all and AltE > Extrude Faces Along Normals:

Select this edge loop:

Fill with F:

Remesh in Sculpt mode (R to set the faces size, CtrlR to remesh:

Result:

Use the Smooth brush to smooth the result:

